# No suitable drivers available when deploying a Spring 6 war to Tomcat 10

Tags: spring, postgresql, tomcat

I have not used this traditional way to deploy wars to a tomcat in the past years.

In these days, I tried to update myself to Spring 6/Jakarta EE 9/Java 17 and created a simple example to demo  a Spring WebMvc war application, when deploying to a Tomcat 10 via cargo maven plugin or manually , I got the famous **no suitable drivers** at the application startup stage when hibernate is initialized.

But it worked in unit tests.

I've also tried to deploy to an external Tomcat server, firstly copy a postgres jar  to the *tomcat/lib* folder, and then copy the war package to the *tomcat/webapps* folder, and start it manually, but got the same errors.

My example project:  https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/tree/master/jpa ,  based on the following tech stack:

- Jakarta EE 9/Java 17
- Spring 6.0.0-M1
- Hibernate 5.6 jakarta variants/Postgres Jdbc Driver 42.3.1
- Apache Tomcat 10.0.14

To reproduce the issues, start Postgres via `docker compose up postgres` and run  `mvn clean package cargo:run -Ptomcat` in the project folder to deploy to the cargo managed tomcat server.

PS: I also configured Jetty and WildFly, both worked well.

**Update**: This issue is a little weird, because packaging Postgres jdbc driver into war worked well with Spring5/Tomcat9. But it failed in this sample which upgraded to Spring6/Tomcat10. To make it work, I have to **exclude the pg Jdbc driver from the war package**, and copy it to the common *tomcat/lib* folder, see the [integration tests](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/jpa/pom.xml#L453) for more details. More about the Jdbc driver loading see @PiotrP.Karwasz's answer.

BTW, Tomcat was the preferred web server for Java developers, one reason was most of the popular Jdbc drivers worked well when packaging it into wars,in contrast most of the traditional application servers(WildFly, Glassfish, etc) did not support it in the past years(you have to install it to application server via the application server command line tools or admin console). But since Java EE 7, it allows developers to define application-scoped `DataSource`s(via `@DataSourceDefinition`) and package Jdbc drivers into the application war packages directly, when the application is being deployed, it will register the Jdbc drivers automatically. Not sure why the newest Tomcat increases the development complexity and uses the legacy application server approach.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using Spring 6?
Because from what I know I do not think it is a stable version. Have you tried using Spring 5 and Tomcat 9 instead? If that passes then you will have your answer if it is a version issue and their stability.

Comment: @zawarudo Just for tasting the upcoming newest stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: in your [`DataSourceConfig`](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DataSourceConfig.java) class you don't call [`DriverManagerDataSource#setDriverClassName`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html#setDriverClassName-java.lang.String-), hence the `DriverManager` does not know where to find a suitable driver for a `jdbc:postgresql:` URI.

**Long answer**: wait, do I really need to specify the driver's class name, aren't JDBC drivers autodetected? Yes, since Java 6 and JDBC 4, JDBC drivers are automatically detected through the `ServiceLoader` mechanism.

However this happens only **once** during the first call to `DriverManager.getDrivers()`. Tomcat makes sure this happens from the server's classpath (cf. [`JreMemoryLeakPrevention`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/cf251fcb8bc699a2629d4b84547ee59896ee94a2/java/org/apache/catalina/core/JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java#L116)), so only the drivers installed globally are registered (no references to application classloaders are held by the system classloader).

Therefore, instead of specifying the driver's class name, you can:

- either install the PostgreSQL JDBC driver in the server's classpath (e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`) and **remove** it from the application,
- or make sure the driver is loaded when your application starts (and deregistered when it stops):

  ```java
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  ```
- you can also emulate the auto-discovery mechanism used by `DriverManager` to register all the drivers distributed with your application:

  ```java
   private static void registerJdbcDrivers(ServletContext context) {
       final ServiceLoader<Driver> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class, context.getClassLoader());
       final Iterator<Driver> iter = serviceLoader.iterator();
       while (iter.hasNext()) {
           // Just for the side-effect of loading the class and registering the driver
           iter.next();
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: The `DriverManagerDataSource#setDriverClassName` or Hibernate dialect is not a must for Spring. Spring will detect the Database type through the datasource url, eg. in this example, `postgres`, and select `Postgres` db type and set the right driver class name. I have mentioned this example worked on Jetty/WildFly, and it is ported from my working Jakarta EE8/Spring 5 based [jdbc example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/jdbc-maven-profiles/src/main) which tested on the popular databases.

Comment: I am not sure what changed in the latest Tomcat. For my previous experience,  most of the jdbc drivers which packaged into a war worked well on Tomcat, except Oracle.

Comment: I have tried to copy the postgres drivers to *tomcat/lib*, it did not work.

Comment: javax packages were renamed to jakarta, they did say that it will be possible in Spring 6 but they never announced it to be a stable version. That's why I suggested and asked if you tried with Spring 5 and Tomcat 9. The latest is never the greatest.

Comment: @zawarudo Almost all Java EE API are renamed to `jakarta` prefix in Jakarta EE 9, except the Jdbc API, etc. for the compatibility, there are still some APIs in the legacy JDKs.  I am sure the similar codes written in Spring 5 working on Tomcat 9.

Comment: @zawarudo It is not a real world application development, just some example projects to update my knowledge.

Comment: @Hantsy: I am not aware of any Spring feature that automatically loads JDBC drivers, do you have any reference? Also I forgot to mention: if you add the driver to `tomcat/lib`, you need to remove it from the application. I locally tested your application and it works.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz [Exclude the pg driver from war package, and copy the pg jdbc driver to *tomcat/lib*](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/jpa/pom.xml#L508), it  works.